# Is there any way to convert these inconvertible types?

Tags: java, generics

At first glance, I would have expected to be able to cast

```
ArrayList<Class<? extends Interface1>>
```

to

```
ArrayList<Class<?>>
```

since the second is clearly a less restrictive version of the first.  However, the following code does not compile:

```
import java.util.ArrayList;

public class TypeInvocationConversionTest
{
  private static ArrayList<Class<? extends Interface1>> classList;

  private static ArrayList<Class<?>> lessRestrictiveClassList;

  public static void main(String[] args)
  {
    classList = new ArrayList<Class<? extends Interface1>>();
    lessRestrictiveClassList = (ArrayList<Class<?>>) classList;
  }

  private interface Interface1 {}
}
```

but produces the error

```
TypeInvocationConversionTest.java:12: inconvertible types
found   : java.util.ArrayList<java.lang.Class<? extends TypeInvocationConversionTest.Interface1>>
required: java.util.ArrayList<java.lang.Class<?>>
    lessRestrictiveClassList = (ArrayList<Class<?>>) classList;
                                                     ^
```

I don't think it's unreasonable to want to convert these two types: for motivation, here's a short program that's closer to what I'm actually dealing with (**this code does not compile**):

```
import java.util.ArrayList;

public class Mammal
{
  public void produceMilk() {}
}

public class Reptile
{
  public void layEggs() {}
}

public interface Species
{
  String getSpeciesName();
}

public class Dog extends Mammal
  implements Species
{
  @Override
  public String getSpeciesName()
  {
    return "Canis lupus familiaris";
  }
}

public class Cat extends Mammal
  implements Species
{
  @Override
  public String getSpeciesName()
  {
    return "Feles catus";
  }
}

public class Boa extends Reptile
  implements Species
{
  @Override
  public String getSpeciesName()
  {
    return "Boa constrictor";
  }
}

public class Panel3 extends Reptile
  implements Species
{
  @Override
  public String getSpeciesName()
  {
    return "Dromiceiomimus brevitertius";
  }
}

public class AnimalFunTime
{
  public static void main(String[] args)
  {
    ArrayList<Class<? extends Mammal>> listOfMammals;
    ArrayList<Class<? extends Reptile>> listOfReptiles;
    ArrayList<ArrayList<Class<?>>> matrixOfAnimals;

    listOfMammals.add(Dog.class);
    listOfMammals.add(Cat.class);

    listOfReptiles.add(Boa.class);
    listOfReptiles.add(Panel3.class);

    ///////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
    // The following two lines cause an error.                                //
    ///////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
    matrixOfAnimals.add( (ArrayList<Class<?>>) listOfMammals);
    matrixOfAnimals.add( (ArrayList<Class<?>>) listOfReptiles);

    // Get milk.
    for (int i = 0 ; i < listOfMammals.size() ; i++) {
      listOfMammals.get(i).produceMilk();
    }

    // Get eggs.
    for (int i = 0 ; i < listOfReptiles.size() ; i++) {
      listOfReptiles.get(i).layEggs();
    }

    // Display all the animals' names.  
    for (int j = 0 ; j < matrixOfAnimals.size() ; j++) {
      ArrayList<Class<?>> currentFamily = matrixOfAnimals.get(j);
      for (int i = 0 ; i < currentFamily.size() ; i++) {
        Class<?> currentAnimal = currentFamily.get(i);
        if (Species.isAssignableFrom(currentAnimal) {
          System.out.println(currentAnimal.getSpeciesName());
        }
        else
        {
          throw new SpeciesNotImplementedException("Please tell us the animal's name!");
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

As the comment says, this code doesn't compile because I am unable to make a list that contains both `ArrayList<Class<? extends Mammal>>` and `ArrayList<Class<? extends reptile>>` objects.  If I could cast those both to `ArrayList<Class<?>>`s, then that would be fine.  Is there a way to do the cast so this sort of thing works?

Comment: It all looks pretty generic already!  What should I be making generic?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

One of the reasons this doesn't (and shouldn't) work is that `lessRestrictiveClassList` would reference the same list object as `classList`. So, if you add an object of type `Class<?>` (where `?` does not extend `Interface1`) to that list, suddenly the contract of `classList` is broken:

```
ArrayList<Class<? extends Interface1>> classList = new ArrayList<>();

// assume this is allowed:
ArrayList<Class<?>> lessRestrictiveClassList = (ArrayList<Class<?>>) classList;

// now add an element to the less restrictive list
lessRestrictiveClassList.add(String.class);

// and obtain it from the original list
// this code will crash, because String does not implement Interface1
Class<? extends Interface1> cls = classList.get(0);
```

The last line will get you in big problems, because it can lead to unexpected failure of code.

Instead of referencing the array list twice, you should make a copy to the less restrictive list:

```
ArrayList<Class<? extends Interface1>> classList = new ArrayList<>();
ArrayList<Class<?>> lessRestrictiveClassList = new ArrayList<>();

lessRestrictiveClassList.addAll(classList);
```

Answer (score 3):

You can do the cast you want by doing two cast in a row:

```
lessRestrictiveClassList = (ArrayList<Class<?>>) (ArrayList<?>) classList;
```

This compiles.

Comment: 'You can [do something to] the first, while you can't [do that] to the second.'  If that doesn't mean that the first is less restrictive than the second, I don't know what does!  However, I see your point: putting two non-primitive objects equal to each other means that they are now the same object, so they have to be exactly as restrictive as each other.

Comment: @Donkey_2009 your first sentence is wright. That part of my answer was plain wrong and I removed it.

Answer (score 3):

> since the second is clearly a less restrictive version of the first.

It is not. `List<A>` is not a subtype of `List<B>` even if `A` is a subtype of `B`. Heuster demonstrated why it's unsafe.

If you don't need to add elements using the second list reference, you should use `ArrayList<? extends Class<?>>` instead. You *can* convert `ArrayList<Class<? extends Interface1>>` to that.

Answer (score 2):

Forget the generics and cast to raw type ArrayList.

```
ArrayList<ArrayList> matrixOfAnimals = new ArrayList<>();
matrixOfAnimals.add(listOfMammals);
```